# chattr: undefined symbol: set_com_err_gettext

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, shell

I've moved my CentOS 6.5 installation to a new server and I'm unable to use chattr on my new server:

```
chattr: symbol lookup error: chattr: undefined symbol: set_com_err_gettext
```

How to resolve this ?

Comment: How did you "moved" your installation?

Comment: Via rsync so it's 1:1 copy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling e2fsprogs fixed the problem ;)